# GTM - How to configure checkout steps and transaction

Tags: javascript, google-analytics, google-tag-manager, google-datalayer

Let me start off by saying that previously the GTM on the site worked well.

One thing I am struggling with now is setting up checkout steps and having GTM still pick up all the transaction data.

Previously I had GTM and the data layer like this at the bottom of the page:

```
    <script>
        dataLayer = [{
            'transactionId': id,
            'transactionAffiliation': '',
            'transactionTotal': totalAmount,
            'transactionTax': totalTax,
            'transactionShipping': ''
        }];
</script>
<!-- #include virtual="/GoogleTagManager.html" -->
```

It picked up the transaction just fine. But i wanted to have checkout steps too.  Now I have tried it like this:

```
    dataLayer.push({
        'event': 'checkout',
        'ecommerce': {
            'checkout': {
                'actionField': {'step': 3},
                'products': [{
                    'transactionId': id,
                    'transactionAffiliation': '',
                    'transactionTotal': totalAmount,
                    'transactionTax': totalTax,
                    'transactionShipping': '',
                    'quantity': 8,
                    'coupon': coupon,
                    'costShirt': +costShirt
                }]
            }
        }
    });
```

and also like this:

```
    <script>
        dataLayer = [{
            'transactionId': id,
            'transactionAffiliation': '',
            'transactionTotal': totalAmount,
            'transactionTax': totalTax,
            'transactionCoupon': 'coupon'
            'transactionShipping': '',
            'transactionProducts': [{
                'sku': id,
                'name': 'sock',
                'category': 'outer',
                'price': costSock,
                'quantity': 1
            }, {
                'sku': id,
                'name': 'shirt',
                'category': 'outer',
                'price': costShirt,
                'quantity': 2
            }]
        }];
</script>

<!-- #include virtual="/GoogleTagManager.html" -->

<script>
    dataLayer.push({ 'event': 'checkout', 'ecommerce': { 'checkout': { 'actionField': { 'step': 3 }, } } });
</script>
```

And its obviously not working well (the other 2 steps in the checkout are just steps, nothing else is being sent to data layer). The other 2 steps are like this:

```
dataLayer.push({ 'event': 'checkout', 'ecommerce': { 'checkout': { 'actionField': { 'step': 2 }, } } });
```

Do you have any suggestions as to how I can get GTM to recognize the transaction again whilst also picking up the coupon and implementing the checkout steps?
I have read that the final part may need to be a purchase event instead of a checkout event. But at this point I am a little unsure of which direction to proceed in